# PHP MongoDB extract File Type

Tags: php, mongodb, file-type, gridfs

I've been working on GridFS with `MongoDB + PHP` and able to perform `CRUD` operations. I need to fetch the file extension types being uploaded. For example see below `type` that is being saved in Mongo for different file types:

```
image = image/jpeg or image/png
text  = text/plain
docx  = application/octet-stream
xlsx  = application/octet-stream
pdf   = application/pdf
```

How can I fetch or convert the above mentioned file types like below

```
image = jpeg or png
text  = txt
docx  = doc
xlsx  = xlsx
pdf   = pdf
```

Is there any function available to achieve the same ?

Also when any `PDF` or `image` of bigger size is uploaded, it inserts more than one records in DB in following form

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("542118ab920662000a000055"),
    "filename" : "blob",
    "type" : "application/octet-stream",
    "title" : "blob",
    "isFolder" : 0,
    "uploadDate" : ISODate("2014-09-23T06:52:27.000Z"),
    "length" : 338277,
    "chunkSize" : 261120,
    "md5" : "d4f9269491c30a0ab086b3bab02c81ee"
}
```

Please Help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply add the needed data on save to the GridFS's entry's [metadata](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/gridfs/#files.metadata) and query for it as you would do with every other collection, eg.

```
db.collection.files.find({"metadata.mimetype":/^image/i})
```

I don't get the point of why multiple records need to be saved, though. GridFS has two collections by default, one which is called files and the other which is called chunks. The latter will hold the file, regardless of it's size, split into - you guessed it - chunks of 255kB. All this is done automatically when using GridFS.

Comment: How to achieve the same using php with mongo ?

Comment: I don't know PHP too well, but I am sure [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongogridfs.php) will help.